# javascript - ceiling of a dollar amount

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point, ceil

So I am adding and subtracting floats in javascript, and I need to know how to always take the ceiling of any number that has more than 3 decimal places. For example:

3.19 = 3.19

3.191 = 3.20

3.00000001 = 3.01

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
num = Math.ceil(num * 100) / 100;
```

Though, [due to the way floats are represented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041816/javascript-rounding-issue/4041838#4041838), you may not get a clean number that's to two decimal places. For display purposes, always do `num.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: this worked great, thank you (it did in fact answer my question). But. . . I am probably going to take Amnon's advice do everything as integers

Comment: @bmarti44, Amnon's advice is good, but a word of warning. Using integers will yield no problems when doing addition and multiplication, but don't fall into a false sense of security: the same problems will arise with division, e.g. `1/10 * 3`. But of course, depending on your application, this may not happen at all.

Answer (score 10):

Actually I don't think you want to represent dollar amounts as float, due to the same reason cited by Box9.
For example, 0.1*3 != 0.3 in my browser. It's better to represent them as integers (e.g. cents).

Comment: I believe you are right to switch the float values to integers, so I will be taking your advice. Thank you for the quick answer.