# javascript round up from 3rd decimal

Tags: javascript, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript - ceiling of a dollar amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817296/javascript-ceiling-of-a-dollar-amount)

I have a number like this: 360.654444444447

I want this to round up to 360.66

How do i do it? The amount of 4's between the 5 and 7 is unknown.

EDIT: The key issue here is that when the decimals after the 2nd would round to 5, it should round up. (ie: 360.654447 can be rounded to 360.655 - and that should round to 360.66

It's similar to the PHP_HALF_ROUND_MODE thing.

Comment: There is a very similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-javascript-round-up-number

Comment: Possibly even more similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817296/javascript-ceiling-of-a-dollar-amount

Comment: So you want 3.5446 to "round" to 3.55 even though 3.54 is closer to the original value than 3.55 (.0046 less as opposed to .0054 more)? Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ceil` method, not the `round` method as others have suggested.

```
var number = 360.654444444447;
var result = Math.ceil(number * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: That comes with a problem. I don't want numbers like 360.2234002 to round up to 360.23... The key issue here is that when the decimals after the 2nd would round to 5, it should round up. (ie: 360.654447 can be rounded to 360.655 - and that should round to 360.66

Comment: But the thousandths place wouldn't round to 5 in that 360.654447... Unless you are talking about rounding multiple times... May I ask why you are trying to do this weird rounding?

Comment: Are you talking about rounding to the nearest half value (i.e. 4.1=>4.0, 4.3=>4.5, 4.6=>4.6, 4.8=>5.0)?

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about rounding half up.

Comment: Please provide more example numbers so that I can get an idea as to what you are talking about.