# Floating value behavior

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)
>   [Javascript rounding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041816/javascript-rounding-issue)

What is the Floating value behavior in java script? How the default precision value behavior?

I was wandering when, I checked

`0.1 + 0.2` in console it give me  `0.30000000000000004`

Can anyone please help me to understand why this happened and its behavior.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is standard floating point rounding issues, which has been asked here countless times. Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041816/javascript-rounding-issue) for instance.

Comment: You need to use Round function and for more info go to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic2.html

Comment: If you only interested to know reason Why it cannot be done then 

"Actually, the error is because there is no way to map 0.1 to a finite binary floating point number."